# Printmail Form inside Colorbox

Tags: javascript

I am actually trying to load the printmail form inside a colorbox. But when I am trying to build up a link like this:

```
<a href="/pages/demo/printmail/64?width=500&height=500" class="colorbox-load init-colorbox-load-processed cboxElement">Send as email</a>
```

The colorbox opens, but returns **"This content failed to load."**
Someone got an idea how to workaround that?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `colorbox-node` instead of `colorbox-load` First check have you already installed the [Colorbox](https://drupal.org/project/colorbox) and the [Colorbox Node](https://drupal.org/project/colorbox_node) modules.

Then, your link would be similar to the following one.

```
<a href="/pages/demo/printmail/64?width=500&height=500" class="colorbox-node">Als E-Mail versenden</a>
```